# How to Apply a Scale transform to an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: avfoundation, swift5, avcapture

I have an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` named `previewlayer` that is set to a `UIImageView` named `VideoOut` that was implemented using Storyboard

The code I used to connect them was as follows

```
    previewlayer.frame = VideoOut.bounds
```

I then wanted to add a "zoom in" button that would scale `VideoOut` by a factor of `0.25` each time the "Zoom In" button was pressed. The method I tried to use is shown below

```
    @IBAction func Zooma(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.VideoOut.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.25, y: 1.25)
    }, completion: nil)
```

Though this does nothing in terms of scaling the ImageView with the video feed. Although when I use the same code on an Imageview not connected to the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` the line of code works as intended.

Any advice or insight would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you need the actual image to zoom, or is sending a zoom command to the camera fine?

Comment: @TheLivingForce sending a zoom command should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a smooth video zoom, try a [zoom ramp](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624614-ramp) on the `AVCaptureDevice` object that the capture layer originates from: `ramp(toVideoZoomFactor: 1.25, withRate: 0.25)`